# Building static lib with state multiple times

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, linker, static-libraries

So I have this example code that I compile using VS to a static library:

```
int val = 0;

int f(int i) {
    val += i;
    return val;
}
```

Because of the global the library has an internal state. I now want to use the function `f` in a program but multiple times and each call having its own state. So I compiled it twice with different names for `f`:

```
int val = 0;

int f1(int i) {
    val += i;
    return val;
}
```

which is compiled to `f1.lib` and

```
int val = 0;

int f2(int i) {
    val += i;
    return val;
}
```

which is compiled to `f2.lib`. Then I tried using it in my program which includes both libraries and looks like:

```
#include <iostream>

int f1(int i);
int f2(int i);

int main()
{
    int x = f1(1);
    int y = f2(1);

    std::cout << x << "\n";
    std::cout << y << "\n";
}
```

However, this doesn't compile I get an error that "`int val` is already defined in `f1.obj`".

This makes sense and could be solved of course by renaming the globals as well. However this is not feasible because for my real code there are too many variables/functions/structs/etc. that would require renaming.

**Question**: How can I compile the library code so that I can include it twice (or even more often), each include has its own internal state and I don't have to rename everything but only the function `f` which is used to interact with the library?

Comment: I think what you are attempting is the wrong approach. It will lead to difficult to maintain code because of all the duplication

Comment: When renaming the function, why not rename the value as well?

Comment: @BoP As I tried to explain, the value is not just a single value. The real library code is huge. This is just a minimal working example to illustrate the core of the problem.

Comment: Maybe put your library's state into a class and make `f` accept a pointer or reference to an object of that class?

Comment: @MilesBudnek This would require a substantial rewrite of the whole library.

Comment: Did namespace work?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT Not really, I couldn't get it working yet because of compile errors when I enclose the library code with namespace...

Comment: **compile errors** Could you provide a sample?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I mean those mentioned in my comment to 463035818_is_not_a_number answer. The problem is that simply enclosing all the code with namespace doesn't work because parts of the code explicitly refer to the global namespace. Of course this could in theory be fixed by refactoring all relevant parts but I want to avoid modifying the library code as much as possible. Ideally I would keep the code as it is and just have a few wrapper functions that interact with the library (in the example this would be the function f).

Answer (score 0):

Different libaries should use different namespaces. Rarely it is a good idea to place stuff in the global namespace. Even then collisions cannot be completely excluded, but there are workarounds for this too. As you are in control of both libraries this isnt an issue here. Instead of renaming the function only, rename the namespace. Ie in the first:

```
namespace lib1 {
    int val = 0;

    int f(int i) {
        val += i;
        return val;
    }
}
```

And accordingly in the other library.

Comment: Is there an alternative to this approach? First I would like to avoid to modify the whole library code and second I couldn't get it to work until now because of compilation errors: simply enclosing everything with `namespace lib1` doesn't work because there are for example calls like `::some_function();` which refer to `some_function` in the global namespace, so its not enough to enclose everything but the code itself must be modified quite a lot: here I would for example have to replace all `::some_function();` calls by `some_function();` or `::lib1::some_function();`...